# how to set time property in ant

Tags: java, ant, properties

I want to have a property with the current time in a specific format:
yyyyMMddhhmm  .
how can I do that in java ant build.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution:

```
<target name="timestamp2">
        <tstamp>
            <format property="current.time" pattern="yyyyMMd_hhmmss" />
        </tstamp>

        <echo message="current time: ${current.time}" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 6):

You use the [TStamp task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html).

```
<tstamp>
  <format property="TODAY"
          pattern="yyyyMMddhhmm"/>
</tstamp>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [TStamp task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html)

for example :

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="propertyName" pattern="yyyyMMddhhmm" />
</tstamp>
```